# update list property using linq join on dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a custom list and dictionary.

```
 class HldSS
 {
      string ID
      string IDLong
      string Name
      // other fields
 }

 class SecurityID
 {
      string ID1
      string ID2
      string IDLong
 }
```

My list hldList is

```
List<HldSS>
```

& my dictionary dicID is (where ID1 is the key value)

```
Dictionary<string, SecurityID>
```

What I am trying to do is populate the IDLong field in my hldList by using the dictionary. So I am trying to write a linq query to update the field IDLong in my hldList by joining my hldList and dicID on the ID field & key value.

However I started to write the query below am unsure how to proceed any further.

```
List<HldSS> res = from hld in hldList
                      join dic in dicID
                      on hld.ID equals dic.Key
```

Example of what I'm looking for

```
 hldList                  dicID
 ID     IDLong            ID1     IDLong
 ABC                      ABC     ABC123
 ABC                      LMN     LMN456
 LMN
 PLO
 ABC
```

Result

```
 hldList
 ID      IDLong
 ABC     ABC123
 ABC     ABC123
 LMN     LMN456
 PLO
 ABC     ABC123
```

Comment: A LINQ query is not supposed to update something, do you want to (re-)create the list?

Comment: ah yes that does ring a bell. Yes re-creating the list would work as long as all the records in hldList are kept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general is a LINQ query not supposed to update something,you have to create a new list.

```
var query = from hld in hldList
            join dic in dicID
            on hld.ID equals dic.Key
            select new HldSS 
            {
                ID = hld.ID,
                IDLong = dic.Value.IDLong,
                Name = hld.Name,
                // other properties
            };

List<HldSS> res = query.ToList();
```

If you want to update the original list you have to loop it:

```
foreach(HldSS h  in hldList)
{
    SecurityID sec;
    if(dic.TryGetValue(h.ID, out sec))
        h.IDLong = sec.IDLong;
}
```

This is also more efficient than the LINQ query.